# Windows 7 .ico file being replaced with cached version

Tags: caching, .ico

I'm having a problem exactly like the one in this very short video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=912c6sQAsH0

I do not feel comfortable running a downloaded .exe file from a third party unknown developer as suggested by the link from the youtube page.

Does anyone know how to manually solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to rebuild the icon cache in Windows 7 **without a restart** is to change momentarily the screen color depth to 16 bits, for example, and when Windows asks you whether you want to keep the changes or not, click "No" to restore the original settings. This will invalidate the icon cache and Windows will recreate it instantly.

Comment: This is a very simple and easy-to-implement solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is something called icon cache. Windows saves all recent icons in one file so that it does not have to gather icons all over the disk. This speeds up the system start.

Googling with the term "windows 7 rebuild icon cache" (without quotes) I was able to determine that icon cache is stored in file `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db` and that all you need to do is rename it and restart Windows, like it's described [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/bea47202-d869-4155-8c8f-2a5b8bd7be1d/). Explorer has a hold of that file so you can't just delete it. There is a `.bat` file that makes it easy to delete the cache. You can download the file from [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html).